# How to disable the close button in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I used matplotlib to create a graphics window, but I do not want the user to manually close it. Is there a way to disable the closing button in the upper right corner? See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GugCZ.png)

Comment: You may look at this question: [How to disable the maximize, minimize and close button of the matplotlib window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303647/how-to-disable-the-maximize-minimize-and-close-button-of-the-matplotlib-window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution will depend on the backend in use.

#### PyQt

For the PyQt backend, you can do the following:

```
import matplotlib
# make sure Qt backend is used
matplotlib.use("Qt4Agg")
from PyQt4 import QtCore  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a figure and some subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2))
ax.plot([2,3,5,1])
fig.tight_layout()

win = plt.gcf().canvas.manager.window
win.setWindowFlags(win.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
win.setWindowFlags(win.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
plt.show()
```

This will disable the close button (not hide it).

[image]

#### Tk

I'm not sure if Tk is able to control the close button. But what is possible is to draw a completely frameless window.

```
import matplotlib
# make sure Tk backend is used
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a figure and some subplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2))
ax.plot([2,3,5,1])
fig.tight_layout()

win = plt.gcf().canvas.manager.window
win.overrideredirect(1) # draws a completely frameless window

plt.show()
```

Comment: OK, but there's still Alt+F4 that closes the window! :)  (In Windows OS)