# Remove borders on PyQt5 QWidget

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am currently trying to display an borderless image on a secondary screen modifying Matplotlib's default figure using PyQT5. For context, this is to display images on a spatial light modulator that uses a simple HDMI output and is handled by my computer as a secondary screen. Its resolution is 1280x1024. I followed the answer at [How to disable the maximize, minimize and close button of the matplotlib window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44303647/how-to-disable-the-maximize-minimize-and-close-button-of-the-matplotlib-window), link but still end up with a border at the bottom of the figure, and borders are added when displaying the figure fullscreen as well. This is the class I use to generate the window :

```
class SLMscreen:


def __init__(self, resX, resY):
    """
    Initializes the window to be displayed on the SLM
    :param resX: Width in pixel
    :param resY: Height in pixel
    """
    #dirty way of finding the primary screen size, could be improved
    app = QApplication([])
    screen_resolution = app.desktop().screenGeometry()
    width, height = screen_resolution.width(), screen_resolution.height()
    mpl.rcParams['toolbar'] = 'None'
    self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(resX / 100, resY / 100), frameon=False)
    self.ax = plt.axes([0,0,1,1], frameon=False)
    self.ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    self.ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    self.fig.patch.set_visible(False)
    self.ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    window = self.fig.canvas.parent()
    window.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)
    window.setGeometry(width,0,resX,resY)
    window.layout().setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    window.layout().setSpacing(0)

    #self.fig.canvas.parent().showFullScreen()
    #self.figManager.window.showMaximized()

def update(self, array):
    """
    Displays the array on the SLM
    :param array: np.ndarray
    """
    self.ax.imshow(array, cmap='gray', aspect='equal')
    self.figManager.window.showMaximized()
```

And I test the good initialization of the window with this very simple snippet :

```
import numpy as np
from SLM import SLMscreen

mask =255* np.zeros((1024,1280), dtype='uint8')
slm_screen = SLMscreen(1280,1024)
slm_screen.update(mask)
```

At the end the window looks like this:

[image: The window still has borders left, right and bottom]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer here : https://discourse.matplotlib.org/t/image-full-screen/19797/2
By adding `window.statusBar().setVisible(False)`, the borders disappear.